# How can I change my welcome message with asp.net identity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've added the following properties to my ApplicationUser class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    // if true, user will be subscribed to the Newsletter
    public bool Newsletter { get; set; }
}
```

My _LoginPartial page obviously doesn't know about this yet and gets its data from the IdentityExtensions:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Welcome back " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
```

The `GetUserName()` function returns the email address. I'd prefer to return String.Format("{0} {1}", FirstName, LastName)

I just have no idea how to extend the IdentityExtensions class so as to add a function that returns the values that I want here.

Where do I start?

Comment: I know about `User.Identity.Name`, did you try if it works for the First Name at least?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `Claims`

Add `claim` to `IdentityModels.cs`

```
public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here

            userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim("UserFullName", string.Format("{0} {1}", this.Name, this.Surname)));
            return userIdentity;
        }
```

And add this `extension` to `Extension.cs` or somewhere you store extensions

```
public static string GetUserFullName(this IIdentity identity)
        {
            string claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirstValue("UserFullName").ToString();

            return claim;
        }
```

After this you can use

```
User.Identity.GetUserFullName()
```

**EDIT**

if you dont want use `extension` you can do it like this

```
public string GetUserFullName(IIdentity identity)
            {
                string claim = ((ClaimsIdentity)identity).FindFirstValue("UserFullName").ToString();

                return claim;
            }

GetUserFullName(User.Identity);
```

Comment: I'm currently not storing extensions anywhere... It's all basically boilerplate at this point.

Comment: You can put extension in any static class and while using it do not forget add namespace of that static class

Comment: Got it thanks. It should work fine when I figure out how to add FirstName and LastName values onto the user record...